# NoReverseMatch at Reverse for '{}' with arguments '('',)'.: ['(?P<id>[0-9]+)/\\Z']

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

```
NoReverseMatch at /Bookstore/book_detail/7/
Reverse for 'edit_book' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['Bookstore/edit_book/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/\\Z']
```

urls.py

```
path('edit_book/<int:id>/', views.edit_book, name = 'edit_book'),
# delete book url
path('delete_book/<int:id>', views.delete_book, name = 'delete_book')
```

Views.py

```
def edit_book(request, id):
    book = Book.objects.get(id =id)
    form = EditBookForm(instance = book)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditBookForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance = book)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'update_book.html', context)

# for deleting the book, takes id as an argument
def delete_book(request, id):
    # getting the book to be deleted
    book = Book.objects.get(id=id)
    # checking if the method is POST
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # delete the book
        book.delete()
        # return to home after a success delete
        return redirect('home')
    context = {'book': book}
    return render(request, 'delete_book.html', context)
```

Error occurs in these lines of template code:

```
<a href="{% url 'edit_book' book.id %}" class="m-2 btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm">Edit</a>
<a href="{% url 'delete_book' book.id %}" class="m-2 btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm">Delete</a>
```

any one help in finding the solution it face noreverse error in the question

Comment: You did not post your template and the error traceback you got

Comment: Please show code of the view which renders `book_detail` template.